# How to Prove That $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0^+}\; e^{- \frac{1}{t}} = 0$?

Tags: calculus

What is the best way to prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0^+}\; e^{- \frac{1}{t}} = 0$? Intuitively, it seems true because as $t \rightarrow 0$ from above, $\frac{1}{t} \rightarrow \infty$ and therefore $e^{-\frac{1}{t}} \rightarrow 0$. Is there a way to turn these observations into a rigorous proof without pulling some magic epsilon from the aether?

Comment: Your limit is correct if by "$t\to0$" you mean $t\downarrow0$.  But $\lim\limits_{t\uparrow0}\ e^{-1/t}\ne0$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I intended; I have fixed the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming we take into account Michael's observation in the comment above, what you wrote *is* a proof, provided you know how to justify the deductions involved.

Indeed, it is true that

> if  $\lim\limits_{t\to b}f(t)=a$ and $\lim\limits_{s\to c}g(s)=b$, then $\lim\limits_{s\to c}f(g(s))=a$.

Prove this in general. Moreover, this is also true when some of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are not numbers but $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, and when some of the limits have the arrow $\to$ replaced by $\uparrow$ or $\downarrow$, provided you combine things correctly. (It is probably a useful excercise to make the complete list of statements of this form that are true, in fact!)

Once you have that, then prove that $\lim_{t\downarrow0}1/t=+\infty$ and that $\lim_{t\to+\infty}e^{-t}=0$.

Finally, put things together.

Comment: No problem.  +1 by the way for your "Prove this in general" (and your answer as a whole).

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $\lim_{t\downarrow 0} e^{-1/t}$ = 0, set 
$$e^{-1/t} < \epsilon.$$
Taking reciprocals, 
$$e^{1/t} > 1/\epsilon.$$
Now take logs on both sides to get
$$1/t > \log(1/\epsilon).$$
Finally invert to get
$$ 0 < t < 1/\log(1/\epsilon).$$

Comment: Typo extripated.

Answer (score 0):

Make $s=1/t$ such that

$$ \lim_{t \to 0^+}\; e^{- \frac{1}{t}} = \lim_{s \to +\infty}\; e^{-s} = e^{-\infty} =0 $$

Comment: Using $e^{-\infty}$ is nothing more that a notation which only serves to hide one of the arguments in the other answers... It should never appear in a «rigorous proof», which is what the OP wants (at least, at the level of someone asking this type of questions!)

Comment: And that is the difference between mathematicians and engineers.